# Webpacker Node Module Bin Error No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, webpacker

I am runnning a rails 5.1.5 app with webpacker 3.5.5. My assets precompile locally without an error. When I deploy to digitalocean server, I get the following error and do not know why.
Here is the output from the capistrano deployment logs:

```
 DEBUG [206c5aa1] Command: cd /var/www/dolgins_production/releases/20190213201703 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" ; bundle exec rake assets:precompile )

 DEBUG [8c98d080]   yarn install v1.13.0

 DEBUG [8c98d080]   [1/4] Resolving packages...

 DEBUG [8c98d080]   success Already up-to-date.

 DEBUG [8c98d080]   Done in 1.65s.

 DEBUG [8c98d080]   Webpacker is installed  

 DEBUG [8c98d080]   

 DEBUG [8c98d080]   Using /var/www/dolgins_production/releases/20190213201703/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths

 DEBUG [8c98d080]   

 DEBUG [8c98d080]   Compiling…

 DEBUG [8c98d080]   Compilation failed:

/var/www/dolgins_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-3.5.5/lib/webpacker/webpack_runner.rb:11:in `exec': No such file or directory - /var/www/dolgins_production/releases/20190213201703/node_modules/.bin/webpack (Errno::ENOENT)

    from /var/www/dolgins_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-3.5.5/lib/webpacker/webpack_runner.rb:11:in `block in run'

    from /var/www/dolgins_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-3.5.5/lib/webpacker/webpack_runner.rb:10:in `chdir'

    from /var/www/dolgins_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-3.5.5/lib/webpacker/webpack_runner.rb:10:in `run'

    from /var/www/dolgins_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-3.5.5/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:6:in `run'

    from ./bin/webpack:15:in `<main>'
```

I am deploying to Ubuntu 14. Not sure what to try. I have looked for solutions but found nothing that has worked.

Thank you.